# Split a string into substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to split a string out into each of it own strings representing each field:

```
name,city,points,score,cards
```

I have these strings:

```
Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0
Anna Grid - Tokyo 16  363 0
Greg H.Johs - Hong Kong -6  363 4
Jessy Holm Smith - Jakarta 8  261 0
```

Format is:

```
Name[SPACE]-[SPACE]City[SPACE]-Points[SPACE][SPACE]Score[SPACE]Cards
```

- Name can have spaces and '.' in it
- City can have spaces in it
- There are sometimes double spaces between ex Score and Points
- Scores, Points, Card can be negative numbers

The rule I would like to implement in Python, is the following:

```
Name : From beginning, until you see "-" - and then strip trailing space from that string.
Cards: From end and back, until you meet the first space
Score: From the space you hit when you made card, go back until next space.
Points: From the space you hit when you made Score, go back until next space.
City: where Name ended and where the Points stopped after seeing the space.
```

My problem here is that I can't just replace space as separator as space can be in name and city, and "-" is being used to separate name and city.

I could do this the brute way and do the stepping through character per character but wonder if Python has a smart way of doing this?

My end result wish is to have each line split up into fields, so i could address ex scorerecord.name, scorerecord.city etc.

Comment: your data is ill formatted - no `-` after the cities.

Comment: yes i know but that cannot be changed, thats why im trying to put order into it with python.

Comment: A regular expression should be able to do this.

Comment: yes ive tried tonnes but nothing really works and i dont fully understand them in depth.

Comment: @MTdrip What can we do about that? Are you expecting us to write the code for you?

Comment: There's a regexp tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: What characters are allowed in the name?

Comment: I think it's permissible to stab people who create ill-formatted data like that. :D You need to be very careful with those dashes: names can be hyphenated; that applies to people and places. Hopefully such hyphens won't be adjacent to whitespace...

Comment: Yes but as i said, i havent made that format so its not in my power to change it - and if you read my post here then what im trying to do is actually to make it correctly formatted. Thank god someone else helped though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `re.match()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

data = '''Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0
Anna Grid - Tokyo 16  363 0
Greg H.Johs - Hong Kong -6  363 4
Jessy Holm Smith - Jakarta 8  261 0'''

data = data.split('\n')
pat = re.compile(r'(?P<name>[^-]+) +- *(?P<city>[^0-9]+) +(?P<points>-?[0-9]+) +'\
                   '(?P<score>[0-9]+) +(?P<cards>[0-9]+)')

result = [pat.match(s).groupdict() for s in data]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'name': 'Paul Grid', 'city': 'Hong Kong', 'points': '56', 'score': '663', 'cards': '0'}, {'name': 'Anna Grid', 'city': 'Tokyo', 'points': '16', 'score': '363', 'cards': '0'}, {'name': 'Greg H.Johs', 'city': 'Hong Kong', 'points': '-6', 'score': '363', 'cards': '4'}, {'name': 'Jessy Holm Smith', 'city': 'Jakarta', 'points': '8', 'score': '261', 'cards': '0'}]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.groupdict

Comment: this is awesome, it works - its still abit of a mystery to me with this regex but hopefully i will learn soon but its amazing !

Answer (score 2):

Just another regex pattern:

```
import re

text = """Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0
Anna Grid - Tokyo 16  363 0
Greg H.Johs - Hong Kong -6  363 4
Jessy Holm Smith - Jakarta 8  261 0"""


print()
pat = r'^([^-]+) - ?([^-]+?)(?= -?\d+) (-?\d+) +(-?\d+) +(-?\d+)$'

for k in re.findall(pat,text,re.MULTILINE):
    print(k)
```

Leads to output of:

```
('Paul Grid', 'Hong Kong', '56', '663', '0')
('Anna Grid', 'Tokyo', '16', '363', '0')
('Greg H.Johs', 'Hong Kong', '-6', '363', '4')
('Jessy Holm Smith', 'Jakarta', '8', '261', '0')
```

Explanation:

- the text parts `'([^-]+) - ?([^-]+?)'` are captured with "One or more anything others then -" with `' - '` between them.
- the second text must be followed `'(?= -?\d+)'`: a (optional) `-` and number(s) via *positive lookahead*.
- the numbers then are captured using `' (-?\d+)'`, again with optional signs. 
  All has to be inside one line `'^ .... $'`, and multiple lines are activated.

Comment: `"Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0"` is splitted as `'Paul Grid'`, `'Hong Kong 5'`, `'6'`, `'663'`, `'0'`? Doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression. I think this covers your rules:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"([\w. ]+?)\s?-\s?([A-z ]+?)\s+(-?\d+?)\s+?(-?\d+?)\s+?(-?\d+)")
r.match("Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0").groups()
```

returns

```
('Paul Grid', 'Hong Kong', '56', '663', '0')
```

You can paste this into https://regex101.com/ for a detailed understanding of how it works

Comment: I don't think this will match `Greg H.Johs`

Comment: I think the spaces around `-` are required, not optional. Probably to allow names with `-` in them.

Comment: thanks, voted the one above as answer i cant put more as answer but you all came up with something that works, and looking like art compared to what i was heading into thanks

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `r'(.*) - (.*) (-?\d+)  (\d+) (\d+)'` in a very simple way will do the matching you described:

```
lines = '''Paul Grid - Hong Kong 56  663 0
Anna Grid - Tokyo 16  363 0
Greg H.Johs - Hong Kong -6  363 4
Jessy Holm Smith - Jakarta 8  261 0'''.split('\n')

import re
p = re.compile(r'(.*) - (.*) (-?\d+)  (\d+) (\d+)')
for line in lines:
    m = p.match(line)
    print(m.groups())

# ('Paul Grid', 'Hong Kong', '56', '663', '0')
# ('Anna Grid', 'Tokyo', '16', '363', '0')
# ('Greg H.Johs', 'Hong Kong', '-6', '363', '4')
# ('Jessy Holm Smith', 'Jakarta', '8', '261', '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the first "-" only like this:

```
name, rest = s.strip().split("-", 1)
```

And you can split the rest on any number of whitespace like this, splitting up to three times only, so whitespace in the city name are preserved:

```
city, points, score, cards = rest.rsplit(None, 3)
```

All that remains now is removing excess whitespace from name and city, which you can do with strip(), and put this in some sort of structure:

```
parts = [name.strip(), city.strip(), points, score, cards]
```